Echo on the other side of the line during calls
I've been facing an issue since the latest updates of Ubuntu 24.04 LTS: during calls, my audio echoes for the person on the other end of the call (note: I don't hear the echo, only the person on the other end does).
I've tested with several of my headphones, and the problem persists with all of them, regardless of model or type.
I've looked into other forums seeking a solution for this issue. I've read about alsamixer, pulseaudio, pipewire, etc. As a beginner in Linux, I found it difficult to understand the solutions proposed elsewhere, but it seems none of them apply to my problem.
I would be grateful if anyone could help me out!
